# Can't Plot Anonymous Function In Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot anonymous function but it gives me error:

```
>> f=@(t) (3*t)/(exp(1)-(8.*t))-2/t.^2;
>> x=linspace(-3,1,50);
>> plot(x, f(x))
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(t)(3*t)/(exp(1)-(8.*t))-2/t.^2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says the dimensions are mixed up. To fully vectorize your function:

```
f=@(t) (3*t)./(exp(1)-(8.*t))-2./t.^2;
x=linspace(-3,1,50);
plot(x, f(x))
```

And here is the results, is this what you are looking for?:
[image]